# Error running custom python memsql pipeline

Tags: python, singlestore, streamline

I tried to create a very simple custom python transformer inside a memsql pipeline, and I got the below error

```
Process terminated with exit code 1: /var/lib/memsql-ops/data/spark/install/memsql-python/python3: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/lib/memsql-ops/data/spark/install/memsql-python/python3)
(hide traceback)

/var/lib/memsql-ops/data/spark/install/memsql-python/python3: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /var/lib/memsql-ops/data/spark/install/memsql-python/python3
```

I'm running on RHEL 6.6

How can I install GLIBC2.14 and 2.17?

Answer (score 0):

the current version of the memsql python distribution is compiled against a version of GLIBC that is newer than RHEL 6.6 provides. this is fixed in the next release (1.2.2) which is coming shortly.